# How to use interesting values with training window in feature tools?

Tags: pandas, featuretools

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft
import featuretools.variable_types as vtypes
#Create item details table
l = [[1, '1', '2018-05-02', 'A', 2.0, 10], 
[1, '1', '2018-05-02', 'A', 1.0, 10], 
[2, '1', '2018-05-28', 'B', 1.0, 40], 
[3, '1', '2018-06-13', 'A', 2.0, 30], 
[4, '1', '2019-08-20', 'C', 3.0, 60]]
item_detail = pd.DataFrame(l)
item_detail.columns = ['Ticket_id','Customer_id','trans_date','SKU','Qty','Amount']
item_detail["trans_date"] = pd.to_datetime(item_detail["trans_date"])
item_detail["index"] = item_detail.index
display(item_detail)
#Create ticket details table
b = [['1', '2018-05-02', 1], 
['1', '2018-05-28', 2], 
['1', '2018-06-13', 3], 
['1', '2019-08-20', 4]]
ticket_detail = pd.DataFrame(b)
ticket_detail.columns = ['Customer_id','trans_date','Ticket_id']
ticket_detail["trans_date"] = pd.to_datetime(ticket_detail["trans_date"])
display(ticket_detail)
#Create feature tools relationships & entities
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'customer_features')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="basket",dataframe=ticket_detail,index="Ticket_id",time_index="trans_date")
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='transactions', dataframe= item_detail,index = 'index')
tr_relationship = ft.Relationship(es["basket"]["Ticket_id"],es["transactions"]["Ticket_id"])
es = es.add_relationships([tr_relationship])
print(es)
es["transactions"]["SKU"].interesting_values = ["A"]
#Create cutoff times table necessary for training window
cutoff_times = pd.DataFrame()
cutoff_times['instance_id'] = es['basket'].df['Ticket_id']
cutoff_times['time'] = es['basket'].df['trans_date']
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                      target_entity="basket",
                                      agg_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                                      where_primitives=["count", "sum"],
                                      cutoff_time=cutoff_times,
                                      cutoff_time_in_index=True,
                                      training_window= '365 days')
display(feature_matrix)
```

**Input data:**
**Item_detail-**

```
Ticket_id   Customer_id trans_date  SKU Qty Amount  index

1   1   2018-05-02  A   2.0 10  0

1   1   2018-05-02  A   1.0 10  1

2   1   2018-05-28  B   1.0 40  2

3   1   2018-06-13  A   2.0 30  3

4   1   2019-08-20  C   3.0 60  4
```

**Ticket_detail-**

```
Customer_id trans_date  Ticket_id

1   2018-05-02  1

1   2018-05-28  2

1   2018-06-13  3

1   2019-08-20  4
```

**Code output:**

```
Ticket_id   time    Customer_id COUNT(transactions) SUM(transactions.Qty)   SUM(transactions.Amount)    DAY(trans_date) YEAR(trans_date)    MONTH(trans_date)   WEEKDAY(trans_date) COUNT(transactions WHERE SKU = A)   SUM(transactions.Qty WHERE SKU = A) SUM(transactions.Amount WHERE SKU = A)
```

1   2018-05-02  1   2   3.0 20  2   2018    5   2   2.0 3.0 20.0

2   2018-05-28  1   1   1.0 40  28  2018    5   0   0.0 0.0 0.0

3   2018-06-13  1   1   2.0 30  13  2018    6   2   1.0 2.0 30.0

4   2019-08-20  1   1   3.0 60  20  2019    8   1   0.0 0.0 0.0

**Expected output**
(for columns   COUNT(transactions WHERE SKU = A)    SUM(transactions.Qty WHERE SKU = A) SUM(transactions.Amount WHERE SKU = A)):

```
Ticket_id   time    Customer_id COUNT(transactions) SUM(transactions.Qty)   SUM(transactions.Amount)    DAY(trans_date) YEAR(trans_date)    MONTH(trans_date)   WEEKDAY(trans_date) COUNT(transactions WHERE SKU = A)   SUM(transactions.Qty WHERE SKU = A) SUM(transactions.Amount WHERE SKU = A)
```

1   2018-05-02  1   2   3.0 20  2   2018    5   2   2.0 3.0 20.0

2   2018-05-28  1   1   1.0 40  28  2018    5   0   0.0 0.0 0.0

3   2018-06-13  1   1   2.0 30  13  2018    6   2   3.0 5.0 50.0

4   2019-08-20  1   1   3.0 60  20  2019    8   1   0.0 0.0 0.0

Answer (score 1):

In the example above, you are correctly using the interesting values with the training window. In the DFS call, the aggregation features are calculated per basket. So, the output feature `COUNT(transactions WHERE SKU = A)` for Ticket ID 3 is 1, because there is only one transaction for Ticket ID 3 where SKU is A in Item Details. The same reason applies for the other expected output features. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Thanks Jeff. I'm trying to get the summary(Sum,count) at a Customer-SKU level using feature tools(An alternative for df.groupby(['Customer_id','SKU']).agg()). Can I use any of the feature tools functions to get this?

Comment: Yes, if  `customers` was an entity and used as the target entity, then `SUM(transactions.Amount where SKU = A)` would be aggregated at the Customer-SKU level.